# Extra Square Brackets being added when deserializing a JSON value with forward slash

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am deserializing two very simple JSON dictionaries:

`{"name": "Premium"}`

`{"na/me": "Premium"}`

The JSON path of the first entry in the first dictionary is "name" (as expected). However, the JSON path of the first entry in the second dictionary is "['na/me']", but I would expect it to be "na/me". Can anyone explain what is happening?

Here is some code to help better understand:

```
string object1 = @"{""name"" : ""Premium""}";
var object1Deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string,string>>(object1);
var object1JToken = JToken.FromObject(object1Deserialized);
Assert.AreEqual("name", object1JToken.Children().First().Path);

string object2 = @"{""na/me"" : ""Premium""}";
var object2Deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(object2);
var object2JToken = JToken.FromObject(object2Deserialized);
Assert.AreEqual("['na/me']", object2JToken.Children().First().Path);
//The above test case passes
```

For some reason, `object2JToken.Children().First().Path` is `"['na/me']"` rather than `"na/me"`. Is this behavior intended? Or a bug?
Using .NET 7.0 and Newtonsoft.Json 13.0.2.

Comment: I'm not sure if `na/me` is a valid path, but I do know that `['na/me']` *is* a valid json path, so at least the output isn't incorrect. I'd assume it is doing this to escape the forward slash.

Comment: `object2Deserialized` is a dictionary. Does it have the correct key as `na/me` ?

Comment: @Sweeper Why would `na/me` not be a a valid path? Could you point me to some documentation on this?

Comment: Well I didn’t say it wasn’t. I just *wasn’t sure*, since there’s the forward slash. The current output is definitely correct, but what you are suggesting could be another correct output too. The only authoritative-looking documentation I could find is: https://www.ietf.org/archive/id/draft-goessner-dispatch-jsonpath-00.html which is still WIP and doesn’t deny that “na/me” is a valid path.

Comment: I tested and could not find any extra quoutes. Try yourself var object2JToken = JToken.FromObject(object2Deserialized).ToString();

Comment: "For some reason, object2JToken.Children().First().Path is "['na/me']"" compiller gives an error "The name 'Children' does not exist in the current context"

Answer (score 0):

Why you use `Newtonsoft.Json` while .NET 7 has a great [built-in standard serializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/how-to?pivots=dotnet-7-0) !!

```cs
using System.Text.Json;

string object2 = @"{""na/me"" : ""Premium""}";
var d = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(object2);

Console.WriteLine(d.Keys.First());
```

the output as you expect

```
na/me
```

Comment: System.Text.Json is only great for the json like this one. For a little more complicated youi will have to spend a month to create a custom converter. And by the way , Newtonsoft.Json works properly, OP just doesn't know how to use.

Answer (score 0):

Your code can' t be even compilled and you have double lines that do the same. Try this

```
string object2 = @"{""na/me"" : ""Premium""}";
var object2JToken = JToken.Parse(object2);
 
Assert.AreEqual("['na/me']", object2JToken.First().Path);

//but maybe it is better

Assert.AreEqual("na/me",JObject.Parse(object2).Properties().First().Name;
```

Comment: My code runs just fine. You might just not have the proper libraries or dependencies installed.